# Replace strings/characters in data frame column

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have a data frame ("GO") in R with 2 columns, "term" and "gene". The "term" column is of type character and has entries like this:

GO_POSITIVE_REGULATION_OF_VIRAL_TRANSCRIPTION

GO_CARGO_RECEPTOR

GO_MATRIX
...

So every column starts with GO_ and has _ between the words. I want to delete the GO_ and replace the other _ by spaces.

I tried to fix this with gsub:

```
GO$term <- gsub('GO', '', GO$term)
GO$term <- gsub('\\_', ' ', GO$term)
```

The problem is that for example GO_CARGO_RECEPTOR has become CAR RECEPTOR, but I need it to be CARGO RECEPTOR.

I don't know how it is possible to specify the code in R, so that in this example only the GO_ in the beginning and the _ in the middle of the strings are deleted...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need only `sub` i.e `sub("^GO_", "", GO$term)` as `gsub` replaces multiple instances of the "GO".  Here, as it is only the starting 'GO", you can add the `^` to mark the start of the string

Comment: Do all strings start with `GO_`? Or do you need to only perform these substitutions if the string starts with `GO_`?

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- "GO_CARGO_RECEPTOR"

gsub("_", " ", sub("^GO_", "", x))
[1] "CARGO RECEPTOR"
```

Just use `sub` instead of `gsub` for the `"GO_"` and `gsub` for the rest.

Comment: Why should `gsub` fail e.g `gsub("_", " ", gsub("^GO_", "", x))`?

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr::mutate` plus some `base` functions to do manipulation in the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
GO <- GO %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(term = base::substring(term, 4), # remove GO_
                term = base::gsub("_", " ", term))
```

```
> GO
                                        term     gene
1 POSITIVE REGULATION OF VIRAL TRANSCRIPTION 0.507617
2                             CARGO RECEPTOR 0.991978
3                                     MATRIX 0.543001
```

---

- Data

```
GO <- data.frame(term = c("GO_POSITIVE_REGULATION_OF_VIRAL_TRANSCRIPTION",
                          "GO_CARGO_RECEPTOR",
                          "GO_MATRIX"),
                 gene = runif(3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need to only replace `_` with spaces in strings that start with a specific prefix and drop this prefix, too, you may use a PCRE regex based `gsub` like

```
x <- c("GO_POSITIVE_REGULATION_OF_VIRAL_TRANSCRIPTION","POSITIVE_REGULATION_OF_VIRAL_TRANSCRIPTION")
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|^GO_)([^_]*)_", "\\1 ", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "POSITIVE REGULATION OF VIRAL TRANSCRIPTION"
##    [2] "POSITIVE_REGULATION_OF_VIRAL_TRANSCRIPTION"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/qMRt8f) and the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/qMRt8f).

**Regex details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^GO_)` - A non-capturing group that matches either the end of the preceding match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) the `GO_` substring (prefix) at the start of a line
- `([^_]*)` - Capturing group 1 (this value is referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern): any 0 or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underscore.